# Should any function be able to work in-place by default

Tags: c++, c++11, in-place

If I am building a library for C++. Is it OK if some functions could not accept in-place operation? would it affect the standard property of the library?

For example:

```
void do_somthing(object const& input, object& output);

int main(){
   object a;
   object b;
   do_somthing(a, b);//OK
   do_somthing(a, a);//wrong
}
```

If it is OK, how should I tell that? for example should I put an assertion? throw exception? Just put it in the documentation and let it produces undefined behavior if someone insists to call it?

**Some clarification:**

In the OpenCV library, some function like `cv::Canny` can work in place like this:

```
cv::Canny(img,img,100,200);
```

However, `cv::warpAffine` can not as it was written in the documentation.

Comment: General hint: make clear what your output is, instead of passing it as a reference parameter. `object do_somthing(object const & input)` is much clearer, instead of returning `void`. Returing a `void` would indicate that this function only has side-effects.

Comment: What is 'in-place operation' and how does the function *accept* it?

Comment: @tillaert you mean instead of returning void ?

Comment: Why do you introduce the chance to misuse a function, and ask for help diagnosing this, instead of doing it the most straight forward way: Have the function return the output. After all, that's what a *function* really is defined to be.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes. Sorry, was still editing my comment.

Comment: @SergeyA See my edit please

Comment: so, by "in place" you mean 'it takes a reference to a non-`const` object and modifies that object'? @tillaert to be fair, in certain circumstances, one must operate via the reference and cannot return a copy.

Comment: @IInspectable To be honest, I saw it a lot that the function return an error_code and the output is a reference parameter.. for that I was asking

Comment: @underscore_d exactly

Comment: Returning an error code is the only option for a library written in C. I would assume, that you are either looking at a C library, or that the author of the library comes from a C background. Or maybe, the library author decided, that exceptions are too much of a hassle to deal with, when targeting multiple platforms.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Functions that return an error code use an old style that you shouldn’t follow in C++, it’s only necessary for languages that don’t know exceptions and compound return values. In C++, you use exceptions or something like a `boost::variant` or `boost::optional` return value to signal failure.

Comment: I see thanks for the comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, the correct way to identify such functions is to have them return the output value:

```
object do_somthing(object const& input);
```

If you *cannot* have them return the output value, and you must instead use an output parameter, then `do_something` ought to either:

1. Perform an in-place operation.
2. `assert(&input != &output)` or throw an exception.

That is, if you can't handle in-place operations, then fail on them immediately. And in those cases, document this fact very explicitly, preferably in a comment on the function's declaration.

Comment: ...and _always, always, always_ have documentation that clearly says what is allowed and what isn't...

Comment: @mindriot Documentation is good but encoding the same information in the type system is better. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph and doing both is best. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can always perform that check yourself, such as:

```
   void do_somthing(object const& input, object& output) {
       if (&input == &output) { // error
```

of course you can avoid the overhead and simply go with tillaert's advice if you can change the signature of the function and return the altered value:

```
 object do_somthing(object const& input) {
```